# Python 3. Что делает эта команда?

Tags: keras, pip, install

Я прописал `pip install -v -v -v -v keras` по совету человека, после чего у меня, что-то установилось, а куда я не знаю. Кто разбирается в этих тегах можете подсказать, что это?

Answer (score 0):

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с ключом -v. Тем более не вижу смысла использовать его 4 раза.
Но вообще `pip` используется для установки пакетов в Python. Если команда выполнилась, то ты установил пакет `keras` в Python. Можешь проверить это в IDLE строкой

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: Я тоже, но он не установился, в конце какая-то ошибка была.

Comment: Пробуй pip install keras.

Comment: А если не пойдет - перейди в командной строке с помощью команд cd в папку, где лежит сам пакет керас, введи dir. Покажется содержимое папки, в том числе и сам пакет керас. И тогда введи pip install "название_файла_пакета_без_пробелов.расширение"

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, не думал, что так можно.

Answer (score 0):

Это та же установка модуля keras, но с более подробным выводом. То есть вместо кратких сведений об установке, выводит все (или почти все) логи.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать, просто у меня в конце всегда ошибка и не знаю что с ней поделать.